# Extra chrome border on <select> items using rounded corners

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, rounded-corners

I have an issue in Chrome where there are "two" borders when I use rounded corners on a select menubox (see below, the top is an input box and the bottom is the select box)

[image: Two borders]

```
input, select { 
    border:2px solid #ced6e9; 
    -moz-border-radius:8px; 
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

I've tried two other approaches, but they don't work:

1. [Rounded corners in Chrome not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467891/rounded-corners-in-chrome-not-working) doesn't work and
2. setting  `-webkit-appearance: none;` but this removes the little button indicating it's a select box

**Edit**
I'm using Windows 7 (service pack 1) with Chrome v18

See this jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BhMMj/1/)

Comment: This sure feels like a bug and it seems to be related to the border-width property in conjunction to the border-radius on the select element. Remove the width, it's fine. Set three of the four sides with a width, it's fine. Set all four borders, problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had this problem before and all I did was remove the border on the select and wrap it in a div with the same style (rounded borders). I'm sure there's a more elegant solution but it was better than searching for hours/days for a solution.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ks5t/).

Comment: please don't make users rely on external sources for an answer, unless  they asked for a link for something. JSFiddle has been down before, could happen again; please edit the code into the answer. :)

Comment: since the OP used jsfiddle in his question, I'm going to assume I can use jsfiddle for the answer.

Comment: OP used a fiddle *in addition* to an example of the code. I can edit it in for you if you like :)

Comment: you can edit whatever you like, but what if stackoverflow goes down... he'll _NEVER_ get the answer! :O

Comment: The anti-link-without-code idea isn't mine, it's a [general policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). That said, you did include an explanation so i'm naturally not flagging or anything, and my first comment was a little off because your answer isn't totally dependant on the link. :)

Answer (score 5):

What version of Windows are you using? Sometimes the OS will force additional graphical quirks onto certain HTML elements. Things appear to behave as desired in Chrome 18 on Windows 7 with an Aero theme enabled. I actually answered a similar question yesterday with an example for styling `select` element to replace the graphical elements lost with `-webkit-appearance: none`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10074928/1030243. Hopefully, if no other solution is found, you can implement it with a few extra lines of CSS.

Comment: yeah, the extra OS stuff is definitely the problem. weird.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 with service pack 1

Comment: note that -webkit-appearance: none will remove the arrow and also includes safari (ipad/iphone etc)

Comment: this question was helpful in replacing the arrows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440019/ie-firefox-custom-drop-down-could-not-remove-native-arrows

Answer (score 0):

set css outline property to none for dropdown...

```
select:focus  
{  
    outline: none;  
}
```

Comment: doesn't work; the outline isn't the problem. There's an extra grey box around it that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomand using a padding instead of margin... it will look better

```
select {        
  -moz-border-radius:8px; 
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /*this one is more important than the moz one*/
  padding:9px;
}
```