# IE & Firefox - custom drop down could not remove native arrows

Tags: css, internet-explorer, custom-controls, mozilla

I'm trying create a custom drop down control and I need to hide the arrows from the native controls. I'm using the following `CSS`, which is working for Chrome and Safari, but not in Mozilla and IE.

```
select.desktopDropDown
{
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle][1].

Comment: What was your solution for IE?

Comment: Please accept the top answer if that's what worked instead of writing the answer within your own question

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use this it will work but with IE10+ and for FF :

Your css should look like this:

```
select.desktopDropDown::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

More about [`::ms-expand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465742.aspx).

Then for the rest :

```
select.desktopDropDown {
    outline : none;
    overflow : hidden;
    text-indent : 0.01px;
    text-overflow : '';
    background : url("../img/assets/arrow.png") no-repeat right #666;

    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
         -o-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
}
```

**Note**: I hardcoded path `"../img/assets/arrow.png"` as background.

This should work good for you in IE, Firefox and Opera .

Comment: Note to those trying this: There is a missing bracket in the first example.

Comment: IE 11 didnt like the spaces in `select.desktopDropDown :: -ms-expand`. It didnt work until I made it `select.desktopDropDown::-ms-expand` (no spaces around `::`.  *IE - trolling since 2009*

Comment: @ug_ Because the good syntax has no spaces. As you can't expect a browser to understand a mispelled JS function, you can't expect it to understand a mispelled CSS instruction. Simple.

Comment: bourbon.io doesn't catch this with `@include appearance(none);` great answer +1

Answer (score 19):

Bare-bones examples:

#### For I.E:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

#### For Firefox:

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    text-overflow: ''; /* this is important! */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Fx I use `-moz-appearance: checkbox-container` which works nicely.

So putting it all together the following should be sufficient for you:

```
select.desktopDropDown {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox-container;
    border-style: none;
}
select.desktopDropDown::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact this trick is mainly required for IE10+ where the arrows are in the Metro style of Windows 8, even on Windows 7. Though Windows 8 users must be used to the style cause it's used through the OS. Anyway, I'd recommend instead of using:

```
display: none;
```

To use:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Because, at least in IE, the former causes the blue line of the selected item to overlay the dropdown arrow when the select is focused, while the latter does not.

Answer (score 0):

we can create custom by using css. tested on IE10, Mozilla and chrome borwser...
Working Example as below :

```css
.customSelect {
  position: relative;
}

/* IE11 hide hacks*/
select::-ms-expand {
display: none;
}

.customSelect:after {
  content: '<>';
  font: 17px "Consolas", monospace;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 11px;
  /*Adjust for position however you want*/
  
  top: 18px;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  /*left line */
  
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.customSelect select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* Add some styling */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: none;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.75;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -ms-word-break: normal;
  word-break: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="customSelect">
  <label>
      <select>
          <option selected> Select Box </option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Last long option</option>
      </select>
  </label>
</div>
```